Вопрос про tkinter (python)
Написал диалоговое окошко, использовав tkinter messagebox. При запуске данного скрипта через Visual Studio открывается только оно. Но после компиляции его в .exe открывается cmd и пустое окно tk. Как сие можно убрать?

При компиляции через pyinstaller:
pyinstaller -F -w my_file.py

Где:
-F отвечает за компиляцию единым файлом
-w глушит консоль
